# Problem with invitation to event in my project

Tags: django, python-requests

i have a following problem...
I create "event" in my project but i can not invite friends to this "event". I don't get how to identify the "event" correctly to make a invite request to friend.

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='creator')
    participators = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    finish = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    event_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-timestamp', )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Event: {self.title} by {self.creator}. \
                Date: {self.event_date}. From:{self.start} to {self.finish}"

    def get_sum_participators(self):
        return self.participators.count()


class EventInviteRequest(models.Model):
    from_event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='from_event', null=True)
    to_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='to_profile', null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"From {self.from_event} to {self.to_profile}"
```

This is a function i'm trying to use, but it sends request to 'event' creator.

```
def from_event_to_user_invite_request(request, id):
    event = Event.objects.get(id=id)
    to_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    event_invite, created = EventInviteRequest.objects.get_or_create(
        request, from_event=event, to_profile=to_profile)
    return redirect('events:event_page', event.id)
```

Could you give me some tips how to fix the problem
Thank you

Update 
Now it's work for me

```
def from_event_to_user_invite_request(request, event_id, profile_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
    event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
    event_invite, created = EventInviteRequest.objects.get_or_create(
        request, from_event=event, to_profile=profile)
    return redirect('events:event_page', event.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the profile_id and the event_id,do not forget to change your url for this to work.

```
def from_event_to_user_invite_request(request,event_id,profile_id):
    event_invite, created = EventInviteRequest.objects.get_or_create(from_event_id=event_id, to_profile_id=profile_id)
    return redirect('events:event_page',event_id)
```

Comment: I tried to do like you said, but got error like 'EventInviteRequest.from_event" must be a "Event" instance'. So i changed a little bit and now it kinda work) Thank you)